# Super Search Doesn't Work on Live server

Tags: supersearch

I’ve just launched a site using Super Search.

Everything works nicely on the dev server but on the live server the search produces no results:

Here is a search for 1 bedroom:

http://demo.alexmarks.com.php53-26.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/properties/search_results/search&bedrooms-from=1&category=&channel=lettings/

which shows 15 results

Same search on the live server:

http://alexmarks.co.uk/properties/search_results/search&bedrooms-from=1&category=&channel=lettings/

which shows 0 results

What could be causing this?

Niall

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue with url paths that weren't changed in the migration. Rookie error but solved.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested things to try:

1. Clear main [**EE cache**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/clear_cached_data_files.html)
2. On the Super Search module page, click on Utilities tab and then Build Search Lexicon
3. Click on Preferences tab and then on Clear Cached Searches